# Return Json Exception

Tags: c#, wcf, facebook-graph-api, rest

The graph facebook API return this error if you dont provide a valid token:

```
{
"error": {
             "type": "OAuthException",
             "message": "An access token is required to request this resource."
         }
}
```

In case you make a valid call the json result is returned.

In WCF with .net 4 how can I return the same Json "exception" with this method:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{id}")]
public SampleItem Get(string id)
{
   if (id.Length != 4)
      "how to return here the error since this method return a sample item class"????
   else
      return rep.GetSampleByID(id);
}
```

Comment: are you asking how to build a JSON string that replicates the Facebook API response?

Comment: No, actualy the question is how to return it?

Comment: You need to clarify what SDK you are using, if any, and where the JSON is coming from (obviously facebook but what is returning it?)

Comment: I'm generating the json myself. In case of an error I want to return the sereliazed error and in case all goes ok I return the serialized class. But all this in the same method.

Comment: Are you just asking about throwing a WebProtocolException? I'm confused

Comment: No, actually I want to return a json string that represents the error not the webprotocolexception. Check my next answer.

Comment: @BeRecursive the question is tagged with WCF, the code posted above is clearly C#/WCF.

Answer (score 0):

I think I find one way. Returning a stream and managing the returning content type. [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746857/can-a-wcf-operationcontract-methods-webget-attribute-have-multiple-responseforma/4092741#4092741)